# Distribution upgrade Error

Tags: upgrade

When I go to System Settings and click on Software Sources nothing happens. When I try

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Failed
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gnome-shell : Depends: libcogl5 (>= 1.7.4) but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: gnome-shell-common (= 3.2.2.1-0ubuntu0.1) but 3.4.0+git20120401.c16dbd76-0ubuntu1~11.10~ricotz0 is to be installed
 gnome-shell-common : Breaks: gnome-tweak-tool (< 3.3) but 3.2.0-2ubuntu1~oneiric is to be installed
 libmutter0 : Breaks: gnome-shell (< 3.3.92~) but 3.2.2.1-0ubuntu0.1 is to be installed
 mutter-common : Breaks: gnome-shell (< 3.3.92~) but 3.2.2.1-0ubuntu0.1 is to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems Gnome-shell stucks the upgrade. You shall try to uninstall the packet and re-install it when the upgrade is done (gnome-shell is available in the repository in oneiric).